# How do I import the tablelayout.jar file?

Tags: java, swing, classpath, package, tablelayout

In every example I can find this import is used: import layout.TableLayout; I´ve downloaded the jar file, but I'm having problems importing it. Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean "I'm having problems..."? What kind of problems? How are you trying to compile your code? Are you setting the classpath? Are you adding the jar file to The build path if an IDE? Consider giving more details that will better help us understand your problem and better allow us to be able to help you.

Comment: I mean that I have imported the layout.TableLayout; and downloaded the .jar file I'm supposed to and I get this error: package layout does not exist import layout.TableLayout;

Comment: You haven't answered my main questions though.  Again, how are you compiling your code? How are you setting the classpath? Are you adding to jar to the build path if using an IDE? These are all important details that you need to fill in.

Comment: Im using textmate to test an example if that answers your question, just realized this is a bit more complicated then I first tought. thanks anyway.

Comment: Textmate is just your editor and shouldn't effect your problem. If you're compiling on the command line again, simply add the jar file's path to the classpath. it means adding two small bits of information to the compilation command, that's all. Nothing complicated at all.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use a jar file, you need to either add it to the classpath. This can be done either by compiling on the command line with the `javac -cp theJarFilePath TheJavaFile.java` command, or by adding the jar to the build path if using an IDE.